# Função scanf() com quantidade variável de parâmetros, como implementar?

Tags: c, parâmetros, scanf

Possuo um arquivo de texto (txt) que contem os seguintes valores:

```
12 90
```

Esses dois valores eu guardo e minhas variáveis `a` e `b`, ou seja `a` é igual `12` e `b` é igual `90`, e estou usando a função `scanf()` para receber esses valores do arquivo da seguinte forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b;

    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

    printf("Valor a = %d, b = %d", a, b);

    return(0);
}
```

Saida:

> Valor a = 12, b = 90

Executo o programa com o seguinte comando `scanfTeste.exe < arquivo.txt` no *prompt* do Windows para rodar o programa.

Entretanto, a estrutura do meu arquivo vai mudar, hora ela vai ter dois valores ou uma quantidade indeterminada, veja os exemplos:

- Exemplo um do conteúdo arquivo: `12 90`
- Exemplo dois do conteúdo arquivo: `12 90 33 77`

Considerando que os valores são separados por espaços, para facilitar a leitura dos dados.

#### Minha dúvida:

Como podem ver a quantidade de parâmetros que passa para o `scanf("%d %d ...", &a, &b, ...)` muda dependendo da quantidade de valores na linha do arquivo, como eu posso fazer com que a função `scanf()` receba uma quantidade de parâmetros de acordo com a quantidade de valores na linha do arquivo?

Comment: Você sabe o número de elementos ou não? Se não souber, a solução que está pedindo não funciona.

Comment: Sim, um dos valores indica a quantidade de elementos no arquivo, e o primeiro valor e em seguida vem os valores.

Comment: Acho que usar um loop que lê um valor de cada vez vai ser mais fácil e simples do que tentar fazer um scanf espertão.

Comment: @hugomg sim eu implementei em um loop com o fscanf e funcionou.

Comment: A descrição da sua pergunta ficou muito boa! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma das formas é usar a leitura normal adaptando às necessidades, algo assim:

```
char arquivo[] = "1 2 3 4 5";
int a, b, c, d, e;
sscanf (arquivo, "%d %d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e);
printf ("%d - %d - %d - %d - %d", a, b, c, d, e);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/O8s6Z6). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/svttdidl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/ScanfVaryingParameters.c).

Obviamente precisa usar o [`fscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) que é o correto para arquivo e não o que eu usei para fácil.

---

Outra possibilidade, **me parece a melhor**, se não quiser criar todas as variáveis e facilitar a leitura seria ler uma por um em um laço. Algo assim:

```
int i = 0;
int tamanho = 5;
int array[tamanho];
FILE * arquivo = fopen("file.txt", "r");
while (fscanf(arquivo, "%d", &array[i++]) == 1);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/IO/ReadFile.c).

---

Também pode fazer isto em listas de tamanho variável com [`vfscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfscanf) dando mais flexibilidade, permitindo que se especifique o formato do dado que será recebido em cada uma das posições. Eu nunca usei e não tenho os detalhes, mas a documentação fornece este exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
 
bool checked_sscanf(int count, const char* buf, const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    int rc = vsscanf(buf, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return rc == count;
}
 
int main(void) {
    int n, m;
    printf("Parsing '1 2'...");
    if(checked_sscanf(2, "1 2", "%d %d", &n, &m)) puts("success");
    else puts("failure");
    printf("Parsing '1 a'...");
    if (checked_sscanf(2, "1 a", "%d %d", &n, &m)) puts("success");
    else puts("failure");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/IO/Vfscanf.c).

Answer (score 2):

Bom se você quiser ler até o final do arquivo faça assim:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a[30], n = 0;

    while(scanf("%d", &a[n++]) != EOF && n < 30)
        printf("a[%d] = %d, ", n-1, a[n-1]);
}
```

O scanf retorna EOF quando chega no fim do arquivo e não tem mais nada pra ler, comparando isso você sabe quando o arquivo terminou!

> Entrada:
>   2 4 23
>   55 12
>
> Saída:
>   a[0] = 2, a[1] = 4, a[2] = 23, a[3] = 55, a[4] = 12,

Se você quiser ler apenas até terminar a linha fica um pouquinho mais complicado:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a[30], n = 0, c;
    char linha[512], *plin;

    scanf("%510[^\n]", linha);
    plin = linha;

    while(sscanf(plin, "%d%n", &a[n++], &c) != EOF && n < 30){
        printf("a[%d] = %d, ", n-1, a[n-1]);
        plin += c;
    }
}
```

> Entrada:
>   2 4 23
>   55 12
>
> Saída:
>   a[0] = 2, a[1] = 4, a[2] = 23,

Repare que dessa vez ele só leu a primeira linha. O %d do scanf não vai te avisar quando pulou uma linha, ele só engole e linha e passa pra próxima. Então se você ler apenas a linha primeiro com o limitador %[^n], que lê até encontrar um \n e depois usar o sscanf nessa linha, você consegue ler apenas os inteiros da linha!

Lembrando que coloquei um limite de no máximo 30 números, você pode aumentar o limite ou fazer um malloc se 30 não for suficiente.

Assim como você usei `scanfTeste.exe < arquivo.txt` para executar o programa. O certo seria abrir o arquivo e usar com fscanf

Answer (score 0):

Em complemento das respostas anteriores, junto mais uma variante para a situação de:

- cada linha tem um número variável de inteiros, no máx. N (exemplo N=4)
- pretendemos lê-los, e saber quantos eram
- estamos a tirar partido de que **`scanf` retorna o número de items lidos**. A função `scanf` é boa para "ler até N elementos..."

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   int i,n, a[4];
   char s[1000];
   while((n=sscanf(fgets(s,1000,stdin),"%d%d%d%d",
                   &a[0], &a[1], &a[2], &a[3])) != EOF ){
      for(i=0; i<n; i++) printf("%d ",a[i]);
      printf(" (%d elems)\n",n);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Entrada

```
1 2 3
1
2 3 4 5
```

saída

```
1 2 3   (3 elems)
1   (1 elems)
2 3 4 5  (4 elems)
```